# Adding to Array in Mongoose Schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
var question = new Schema({
  question: String,
  answer: [{ body: String}]
})
```

Adding 'answers' in Database?

Edit:-

I'm trying:- But it says:- `Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array`

```
questionModel.findByIdAndUpdate(ans.id, 
            { $push: { answer: { body: ans.answer.body} } },
            function(err){ if(err){ 
           console.log(err) 
         } else { 
            console.log('Added')
         }
      });
```

Comment: Your question Schema and findByIdAndUpdate statement look fine to me. So the error must be somewhere else. Could you post the result of how a question is stored in the db ( db.questions.findOne({"_id": ObjectId("...") }). How do you export and create the questionModel.

Comment: You might be missing {upsert:true} so that it will also insert the value in the case that the array doesn't exist yet.